# .map is undefined before this.props.action executes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, array.prototype.map

So I am getting an error stating that .map is undefined because I am assuming this.props.action is not finish and therefore makes the .map unable to map anything.

reducer

```
 case GET_DEALERSHIP_GOAL_TYPE_SUCCESS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        loading: false,
        dealershipGoalType: action.payload.data
      });
```

mapStateToProps

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  dealershipGoalType: state.DealerPreferencesReducer.dealershipGoalType,
});
```

componentDidMount

```
  componentDidMount = () => {
      this.props.actions.getDealershipGoalType(this.state.prevId, this.state.year)
  };
```

Render

```
render = () => {

 let {dealershipGoalType } = this.props;
}
```

map section

```
  {dealershipGoalType.map(goal => (
      <option value={goal.type_goal}>
        {goal.label}
      </option>
  ))}
```

any ideas?

Comment: you, can have a default value for `dealershipGoalType` as empty array.
Also, you can check for `dealershipGoalType` and if it's empty render empty state or show loader if it's loading

Comment: Set a defaultValue as an empty array. `let {dealershipGoalType = [] } = this.props;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the initial state of `dealershipGoalType` to be an empty array, other than that I would suggest you to show an empty text or some sort of loader until you get anything in the `dealershipGoalType`.

```
{
  dealershipGoalType.length > 0 ?
   dealershipGoalType.map(goal => (
    <option value={goal.type_goal}>
     {goal.label}
    </option>
  )
 : <span> There are no listings! </span>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of **Nullish Coalescing Operator** which came out in ES2020. In your render, use

```
let dealershipGoalType = this.props.dealershipGoalType ?? [];
```

In this way if the dealershipGoalType is empty, it will automatically assign an empty array dealershipGoalType without breaking the code. Moreover, it reduces the amount of code to be written in order to cater this problem and makes the code look clean as well.

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator).